# When i play continuous media sound on javascript in phonegap after i played it 20 times or more the sound stops

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

is there any limitation to the phonegap or javascript when it comes on audio media playing? Thanks for advance answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13568257/949476

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a limitation in the number of active media object, so don't forget to release the object before creating another one.

Comment: thanks i find the solution, you are correct i need to release it after using it.